# Bisection Method Jupyter Notebook

Tags: math, jupyter-notebook

Using bisection method to find p3 for f(x) = sqrt(x) - cos(x), I got the right answer on paper p3 = .625

I am having a trouble converting the problem and solving it using Jupyter notebook. Any tips?

[Jupyter Notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpVa9.png)

Comment: One thing that would help in researching implementations that would be out there would be to specify in your search the language you are using. Jupyter can run all sorts of languages depending on the kernel, usually indicated somewhere on the upper right side of the interface. I see `import math` as your first line and so it looks like it is Python? Jupyter is like a integrated development environment and one of the languages used a lot with it happens to be Python. (In fact the legacy of the project relates to IPython notebooks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.625 is the third guess in the approximation process so the for loop should be completed before the fourth iteration and the code should be as follows.

```python
import math

##problem statement
#finding a root of f(x) = sqrt(x)-cos(x) between the interval [0,1]
#f(0) = -1 f(1) = 0.45969..  so there is at least one root between the interval [0,1]

a = 0
b = 1
maxIt = 100
negative_result = math.sqrt(a) - math.cos(a)
positive_result = math.sqrt(b) - math.cos(b)

for i in range(maxIt):
    if i == 3:
        print("answer is: ", guess)
        break
    guess = (a+b)/2
    guess_result = math.sqrt(guess) - math.cos(guess)
    if guess_result*negative_result >= 0:
       a = guess
    else: 
        b = guess
```

And the output is

```
0.625
```